# WPF Combobox Items Display Query

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a list of double values to be placed into a combobox.
When the data is a whole value, I discover they drop the decimal place.
How can I show the items up to 2 decimal place even when it is a whole value?

xaml

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxValue"/>
```

Codebehind

```
List<double> valueList = new List<double>();

for(double i=0; i < 3; i = i + 0.5)
{
    valueList .Add(i);
}

cbxValue.ItemsSource = valueList;
cbxValue.SelectedIndex = valueList.Count - 1;
```

Output:

- 0
- 0.5
- 1
- 1.5
- 2
- 2.5
- 3

Required output:

- 0.00
- 0.50
- 1.00
- 1.50
- 2.00
- 2.50
- 3.00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `ItemStringFormat` of your combobox in order to format the decimal value to decimal points. For two decimal points you can set ItemStringFormat as

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbxValue" ItemStringFormat="F2"/>
```

or in code behind

```
cbxValue.ItemStringFormat="F2";
```